# php code for uploading/changing Image for an existed user from android after logging in

Tags: php, android, mysql

My table into the databases has 5 columns: id, username, email, password, image_path. id, username, email and password columns are filled while user registering but iamge_name column must be filled after logging in by uploading a picture from gallery. Also i need that user can change his/her picture.

for example the table is like this:

*id------username------email------password------image_path*

1----------alex--------a@g.com-----123456-------

2----------alex2------a@g2.com----123456-------

now i need to insert an image for alex2. please help me first to find where alex2 there is and then insert the picture to the image_path column of id=2(where username is alex2). So please help me to complete this code:

```
        public function insertImageByUsername($username){
        //here i want to find row related to alex2
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT id FROM my_table WHERE username = ?");
        //here i want to insert image to the image_path column of alex2 related row
        $stmt2 = $this->con->prepare("INSERT INTO `my_table` (`image_path`) VALUES ( ?);");

    }
```

thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: _I don't know how can i write php code for uploading/changing an image for an existed user after logging in?_ **so ?**

Comment: This is not a **please write my code** service. You need to do your research on your own. There are many tutorials available that cover this. Refer them, try them and if you face any particular issue come back here with the code that you tried.

Comment: i need only edit my above code. i put my code now. i dont know how can i fill image_path for a certain user in my table

Comment: @Prerak Sola, I edited my question